# Change time output using php

Tags: php, time

I have a time average total that is computed from a time converted from an integer.

```
average = 0:0:20
```

I wanted to change its output like this:

```
average = 00:00:20
```

By the way, this is the code I used to get the time average:

```
$ans = $times / $displaycount;
$hh = floor($ans / 3600);
$mm = floor(($ans - ($hours*3600)) / 60);
$ss = floor($ans % 60);

$timeavg = $hh.':'.$mm.':'.$ss;

echo "average = ". $timeavg;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$str= '0:0:20';
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($str)); //output :- 00:00:20
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use format function like [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```php
$timeavg = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hh, $mm, $ss);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/137402)</kbd>